# creating shared library from c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll

when I tried to create a shared library file using a "cl" command in vc++, it showed an error saying that `"fatal error c1083: can't open compiler generated file 'file.obj':permission denied"`. 
Can anyone help me...???

Comment: Why is this tagged as "java"?

Comment: In which directory are you trying to compile it? What command are you exactly typing? (@Neil Butterworth: retagged)

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>cl -I"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\include" -I"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\include\win32" -I"c:\Users\402100\Documents\jni and cpp\jni\build\classes\jniandcpp\Main.h" -LD "c:\Users\402100\Documents\jni and cpp\jni\build\classes\jniandcpp\file.cpp" -Fe newfile.dll




this is the command wat i am typing...

Comment: hi Neil, i thought tat java is enough, instead of typing the whole tag "java native interface"

Comment: @robi: What does Java *or* Java Native Interface have to do with the question?

Comment: from a java program i need to call the native functions written in c++. in order to perform that i need the shared  library created using the above given command...

Answer (score 2):

The permission denied error comes in because of your current working directory "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC" is where the compiler is going to write it's temp files, etc (because you've not specified an alternate path). You likely don't have write access to this location, hence the error.

You basically have two options:

1. Change directories to a location where you've write access and then invoke cl.exe. (If you're using the Visual Studio command prompt, cl.exe should be in your path and you shouldn't have to worry about specifying a full path to the compiler).
2. Specify an output directory for your DLL (and the compiler will use the same path of the intermediate files).

Answer (score 0):

It's Open in write mode by some other application i guess...

Comment: I don't know... ideally Permission is Only denied if
1> it's open by other application
2> you do not have the rights (Administrator or other user has restricted this file's rights)
3> It is not properly closed by previous application